# Utilizar print(eval(variable) python 3

Tags: python-3.x

soy nuevo por aquí, me gustaría saber si alguien me puede ayudar.
Tengo una duda, necesito formar la siguiente cadena de datos [numero1 + signo4 + numero2 + signo3 + numero3 + signo2 + numero4 + signo1 + numero5]

Los numeros son aleatorios del 1 al 9
Los signos son aleatorios (+,-,*,/)

quiero utilizar la función print(eval(variable)) para obtener el resultado sin embargo me sale un error.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import random

signos = ['*', '/', '+','-']
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

random.shuffle(numeros)
random.shuffle(signos)

cuenta = 0

expresion = []

for numeros_i in numeros:
    expresion.append(numeros_i)
    cuenta = cuenta + 1
    if cuenta == 5:      
      print(str(expresion[0]),signos[0],str(expresion[1]),signos[1],str(expresion[2]),signos[2],str(expresion[3]),signos[3],str(expresion[4]))
```

Mi resultado es: `2 * 8 / 4 - 7 + 9`

Sin embargo cuando utilizo la función print(eval(....)) me aparece lo siguiente:

```
TypeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9c5eb0d41578> in <module>()
15     cuenta = cuenta + 1
16     if cuenta == 5:
---> 17       print(eval(str(expresion[0]),signos[0],str(expresion[1]),signos[1],str(expresion[2]),signos[2],str(expresion[3]),signos[3],str(expresion[4])))
TypeError: eval expected at most 3 arguments, got 9
```

Ya intente guardar el resultado en una variable para después aplicar print(eval(...))

```
expresion2 = (str(expresion[0]),signos[0],str(expresion[1]),signos[1],str(expresion[2]),signos[2],str(expresion[3]),signos[3],str(expresion[4]))

print(expresion2)
('7', '/', '4', '-', '6', '+', '9', '*', '2')
```

después utilizo

```
print(eval(expresion2))
```

sin embargo no funciona, me aparece lo siguiente:

```
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

Lo que quiero obtener es algo así:

```
resultado = ""1-2+3/4*5"
print(eval(resultado))

2.75
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Le estás pasando demasiados argumentos a la función `eval`, solo necesita la expresión a evaluar.

```
import random

signos = ['*', '/', '+','-']
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

random.shuffle(numeros)
random.shuffle(signos)

cuenta = 0

expresion = []

for numeros_i in numeros:
    expresion.append(numeros_i)
    cuenta = cuenta + 1
    if cuenta == 5:      
      print(eval(str(expresion[0])+signos[0]+str(expresion[1])+signos[1]+str(expresion[2])+signos[2]+str(expresion[3])+signos[3]+str(expresion[4])))
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, me podrías sugerir algún código para modificarlo?

Comment: Este código funciona con la modificación que le realicé, y esta bastante bién, si quieres puedes separar la cadena a evaluar y colocarla en una variable, luego llamarla dentro de eval(), eso simplifacaría un poco más el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias! no había notado el cambio de los + que colocaste

Comment: Por nada, me alegra haberte ayudado.